# FireFox has stopped showing JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Last night, I was trying to debug a particular bit of vanilla JavaScript on a private page.
After a half an hour or so, the browser crashed while in the middle of stepping through a troublesome section.
When FireFox restarted, FireBug insisted that there was no JavaScript on the page - does anyone have any ideas what is causing this? Clearly the JS was (nearly) valid before the crash, and wasn't changed before I restarted. <strike>The only thing I can see, is that FireBug probably installed an update at that point?</strike>

I've tried cutting out all of my code, but nothing seems to make a difference. Other pages, even on the same intranet site, still work, but this one doesn't list any files under the "Script" drop down.

I've compared with the built-in Dev tools, and they also show no JavaScript loaded. The JS is a form submission handler, and clearly it is no longer running when the form is submitted.

Comment: maybe firebug refered to the wrong tab or page? Make sure that you have pressed F12 on the correct tab.

Comment: I usually have FireBug docked to the bottom of the screen, so I can be 100% sure that was not the case here.

Comment: Does the Firefox devtools debugger panel agree with Firebug?

Comment: Actually it does, and the NET panel on both says that only the HTML CSS and images were fetched, so presumably this is actually a FireFox problem.

Comment: Reinitialize your profile?  (read carefully what it does) https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems

Comment: Surprisingly, that worked. Seems VERY strange that this would affect two completely different machines almost simultaneously, and only this one page.

Comment: Today I started to experience the same problem - the browser behaves as if javascript is disabled, at least on some domains, though the javascript.enabled config setting is true. Pages are not loading js, and <noscript> content is being displayed. Strange indeed.

I tried resetting firefox per @fflorent's suggestion, but my Troubleshooting Information page does not have the requisite button. Guess I have to try a fresh profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this for much of today. Eventually resolved it by creating a new profile.

I would be very interested in learning of the root cause if anyone figures it out.